# VBA remove duplication object array error

Tags: vba

overlapArr and uniqueOverlapArr are both class object “clsOverlap” with multiple variables. However the code below has Runtime error ‘438’: OIbject doesn’t support this property or method.

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long

    Dim uniqueOverlapArr() As clsOverlap
    ReDim uniqueOverlapArr(0 To 1)
‘overlapArr is object array to remove duplications    

    For i = 0 To overlapArr.length - 1  ‘over 1mil indexes

        If Not uniqueOverlapArr(0) Is Nothing Then ’check if first index is empty
            For j = 0 To k
            'CHECK DUPLICATION HERE
                If (uniqueOverlapArr(j).grp_id = overlapArr(i).grp_id)) Then GoTo nxt

            Next j
        End If

        Set uniqueOverlapArr(k) = New clsOverlap
        uniqueOverlapArr(k) = overlapArr(i) ‘Error here 438
        k = k + 1
        ReDim Preserve uniqueOverlapArr(k)
nxt:
    Next i
```

I don’t understand the error here, overlapArr is previously defined as clsOverlap

Comment: Why won't a collection or dictionary object work?

Comment: Im iterating through 1mil indexes. Both collection and dictionary would take too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: found problem, just add "set" prior to line with error